# Compare two columns and clear contents if duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare columns A and B and clear the duplicates in column B.

```
Sub deleteDoublicates()
Dim i As Long
With Sheets("Tabelle1")
    For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Application.IsNumber(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A"), Sheets("Tabelle1").Columns(1), 0)) Then
            .Cells(i, "B").ClearContents

        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

There must be something completely wrong because it deletes all.

Comment: I don't understand your logic in the match / clear loop. Won't it always return a match for every row, even if there is only one value in col A, because when you match, say, row 200 of column A against Col A then it will match itself, i.e. the match will return 200, in which case it will then clear the entry in Col B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch errors from application.match with a variant.

```
Sub deleteDoublicates()
    Dim i As Long, m as variant
    With Sheets("Tabelle1")
        For i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            m = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A"), Sheets("Tabelle1").Columns(1), 0)
            if not iserror(m) then
                .Cells(m, "B").ClearContents
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Your own code was iterating i through the rows in column A but inexplicably using that row number to clear column B.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with the relation between column B and Sheets("Tabelle1").Columns(1).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!